# android 4.0 spinner usage

Tags: android, popup, spinner, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I want to be able to do what is on the picture, provided by this [link](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/app-structure.html), under the "Allow cutting through hierarchies" section. I thought that I could do that using a spinner, but from the android documentation I realized that a spinner can show one child at a time and lets the user pick among them. In my case, (and from the example I provided), you have some other text displayed, and then you can choose from some other options provided in sth that looks like a popup, list that contains the things that i want to choose from. I don't know how this is implemented, but it's used in the google music app for android 4.0. If someone has an idea, have implemented sth like this, please give me some advice.

Comment: It's probably a [Menu](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html)

Answer (score 0):

It is not a spinner. Its just a view (in the Mail app a relative layout) See [here](http://source-android.frandroid.com/packages/apps/Email/res/layout/action_bar_spinner.xml)

On click this View opens a popupmenu.

Therefore it is looking like a spinner but you can add you custom behaviour.

Comment: Thanks for replying, but, I found what I was looking for. In order to achieve what I wanted to do, you need to use a popupMenu. This works for 3.0+ only, and since I am building my application for android 4.0, I can use it.